# Replacing all multispaces with single spaces

Tags: python, string

For example

```
s = "a b        c d    e                            f  "
```

Needs to be reduced to

```
s = "a b c d e f "
```

Right now I do something like this

```
for i in xrange(arbitrarilyHighNumber,1,-1):
    s = s.replace(" "*i," ")
```

But I want to make it more dynamic and Pythonic (and assume any number of spaces, too). How can I replace every contiguous space threshold with a single space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "a b        c d    e                            f  "
>>> re.sub('\s{2,}', ' ', s)
'a b c d e f '
>>>
```

`\s{2,}` matches two or more whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1):

Since the regular expression answer has already been given.  You could also do it with iterative replacements.

```
while s.find("  ") is not -1:
    s = s.replace("  ", " ")
```

My original answer of splitting and rejoining gets rid of the leading and trailing whitespaces

```
' '.join(s.split())
```

Comment: This is almost correct, but it removes the trailing space that the OP wanted in his example.

Comment: You lose the first/last space: `' '.join(' a '.split())` -> `'a'`

Comment: True, I usually assume people don't want trailing whitespaces.  I edited my answer to include one that doesn't use regular expressions to add some diversity