# remove space in file line's data

Tags: python

I am trying to fetch data from a file but data is not coming properly because no. of spaces are different at different places.

Ex: file have following below given data. here every word have more than one space(Note this is not string, its a file data and i m using `readlines()`)

```
08:30:34  Lane   2  Typ   1  Prt  1  Tid     2  Amt       4.99  Mode   0  Tndr   1  Oper       130  Tran        74  ID  53062261  Log Dt 2014/08/05  Log Tm 08:30:34  LaneType 1  HasPrinter 1
```

I want output like this :

```
08:30:34 Lane 2 Typ 1 Prt 1 Tid 2 Amt 4.99 Mode 0 Tndr 1 Oper 130 Tran 74 ID 53062261 Log Dt 2014/08/05 Log Tm 08:30:34 LaneType 1 HasPrinter 1.
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing all multispaces with single spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022052/replacing-all-multispaces-with-single-spaces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use regex :

```
>>> s="08:30:34  Lane   2  Typ   1  Prt  1  Tid     2  Amt       4.99  Mode   0  Tndr   1  Oper       130  Tran        74  ID  53062261  Log Dt 2014/08/05  Log Tm 08:30:34  LaneType 1  HasPrinter 1  "
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(' +',' ',s)
'08:30:34 Lane 2 Typ 1 Prt 1 Tid 2 Amt 4.99 Mode 0 Tndr 1 Oper 130 Tran 74 ID 53062261 Log Dt 2014/08/05 Log Tm 08:30:34 LaneType 1 HasPrinter 1 '
```

so if you want to keep a list from `readlines()` :

```
>>> f = open('yourfile.txt','r')
>>> result=[re.sub(' +',' ',i) for i in f.readlines()]
```

Comment: thank you reply , I am new in python and i tried this but it is working only for string. i am using below code
f = open( sys.argv[1], 'r')
lines  = f.readlines()
f.close()
that data is written in file and i am reading that file and i want to remove extra space from file .. in each line

Comment: `readlines()` return a list of each line of your file, you can iterate through the list and apply the regex method (see Edit)

Comment: i need one more , i want to write a code where a function take two file as a input and compare both file data and return out if any mismatch found in both file data. once again thanks for help

Comment: This is an other question, please open other question is you do not find already the answer (I think you'll find here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120489/compare-two-files-report-difference-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
s = 'aaa bb    ccccc    d f    ggggg'
s = ' '.join(s.split())
```

If you are reading from a file with `readline()`:

```
with open('bar.txt', 'r') as f:
    while True:
        s = f.readline()
        s = ' '.join(s.split())
        if not s:
            break
        print(s)
```

Comment: thank you reply , I am new in python and i tried this but it is working only for string. i am using below code
f = open( sys.argv[1], 'r')
lines  = f.readlines()
f.close()
that data is written in file and i am reading that file and i want to remove extra space from file .. in each line ..